# AJAX POST does not always occur

Tags: ajax, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have tried to incorporate AJAX into an application that I built.

The basic function is:

-The user clickes a button, which triggers JS code that makes an AJAX call that does a POST to a Servlet(sending account data).

-The Servlet(which has an EJB injected into it), communicates with an EJB through it's local interface.

-The EJB(on init) initializes a DAO object, injects an EntityManager into it, and uses that DAO object to communicate with a database through JPA (Hibernate as the provider).

-The local interface methods of the EJB return Data Transfer Objects, which are parsed in the Servlets doPost() method, and the DTO's are used to build an HTML table(String) that the Servlet responds to the AJAX call with.

-On the client side, I use that HTML table(responseText) to update a div on the page.

I have 2 questions:

1) Is using a data-centric approach to the AJAX call (returning an HTML table instead of JSON Strings) a common choice in enterprise level applications that make use of AJAX?

2)I've noticed that sometimes the POST is not even called. It seems to be intermittent. I tried to add the Cache Control header, but that doesn't seem to work. This concerns me especially when I think about eventually deploying the application to production, that maybe AJAX is not the way to go, but when it works, the application works smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

1) Using AJAX to submit data or update the web page is very common. Page at a time applications are the old way web applications used to be done where you would need to reload the entire page just to update a little bit of information - which would be inefficient and not to mention would create a bad user experience. These days, updating just "Part of a page" is very common and is mostly done using AJAX, and if not WebSockets.

Now you question regarding updating the page using the servers response which is HTML - to update the page, or just get a JSON String, and manipulate the DOM (ie adding tables etc). I have used a combination of these. For example if needed to add a row to a table, you could get the server to generate the HTML using a tempting engine (groovy or similar). In addition you you need a response code, so you can package the HTML and Response code in a JSON, and send it back to the client. Any combination of these works depending on your use case.

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("responseCode", responseCode);
json.addProperty("html", html);
```

2) You can write a simple script to send multiple requests to the AJAX url to see if it is the server that is not able to handle the amount of requests. If it works, then you can narrow down the problem to be client side. Make sure you are not using blocking techniques. You can also setup a callback function to see if there is any response if any. AJAX Post is similar to a normal POST request, just make sure you have some indicator for the user notifying them that the request is in progress/complete.